# Given $f(x+1)=x^2-3x+2$, how can I find $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given $f(x+1)=x^2-3x+2$, how can I find $f(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=x+1$. We then have $x=y-1$. Hence,
\begin{align}
f(y) & = f(x+1) = x^2 -3x+2 = (y-1)^2 - 3(y-1)+2\\
& = y^2-2y+1-3y+3+2 = y^2-5y+6
\end{align}

Comment: wow,thank you,so answer is y2−5y+6? i tried to solve this all day long ,thank you one more time :)

Comment: As $f(x+1)=(x-1)(x-2)$ it's zeroes are 1 and 2, so $f(x)$ has zeroes 2 and 3, hence $f(x)=(x-2)(x-3)$.

Comment: I may be wrong but I just want to put forward a point. The answer you have given is f(y). We have to find out f(x). Your answer may be a hint but if you could please extend your answer

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

$$f(x)=f((x-1)+1):=(x-1)^2-3(x-1)+2=x^2-5x+6$$

This, of course, is the same as the other answer but without introducing a new variable